# Gitlab: папка для веб интерфейса

Tags: git, gitlab, vesta

Установил себе gitlab на сервер. при установке указал поддомен своего сайта, например, ***git.mysite.com***. После установки перешел по адресу, поддомен не находится. Логично, так как я его не создал. Перешел в настройки (у меня Vesta CP), создал поддомен в DNS. Теперь он показывает на основной сайт.

На сколько я понял, теперь мне надо в настройках nginx указать папку для web интерфейса gitlab.

В этом и вопрос: а где она? Я искал в документации - не нашел. Гуглил - не нашел. Помогите, если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой

Comment: Непонятно. Гитлаб установлен под вестой или на отдельном сервере, а в весте только днс настраивается?